# Adding bot to post in telegram channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

1. I have a Telegram Channel and I am the admin/creator of it
2. I created a bot through botfather
3. I added this bot as admin in by Channel
4. I connected this bot with an external service so that content gets automatically posted in my channel.

Problem is
When external service post content, it shows up in my bot, but it is not showing up in my channel.... As it is showing in my bot, so it is confirmed that external service and bot are connected perfectly........but bot and channel is not connected properly.....

Please help, what should I do?

Comment: Make sure that you've given send message permission to the bot. go to Manage channel > Administrators > Check permission of your bot.

Comment: Yes Nabi, given all permission.

Comment: you should unveil more details of your code, parameters and request. to me and others be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody for answering. Now, the problem is resolved now.

I waited for 2 days, but it was not working. Then I created new bot and added again. And now, it is working fine.

Once again thank you everybody for your helping hands.